# OCPSoft Rewrite - Response already committed error

Tags: java, jsf, url-rewriting, ocpsoft-rewrite

I’m new to Rewrite and I’m just trying to make my test application work with it using simple redirect rules.

But for every redirect event I’m getting “Response already committed” error in log, in spite of redirect works well and I can see target page in my browser.
I checked it with Glassfish 4.1 and Wildfly 9 – the problem is same. I already read this thread – https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/issues/151 , but the workaround doesn’t work for me.

I’m using the latest stable version of Rewrite – 2.0.12.Final by Maven.

Here is stack trace for Wildfly:

```
14:26:17,805 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005023: Exception handling request to /untitled65_war_exploded/index.xhtml: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010019: Response already commited
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.resetBuffer(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:715)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.resetBuffer(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:483)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.resetBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:241)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpRewriteWrappedResponse.resetBuffer(HttpRewriteWrappedResponse.java:480)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:147)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:108)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpRewriteResultHandler.handleResult(HttpRewriteResultHandler.java:41)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.rewrite(RewriteFilter.java:268)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:188)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**ExampleConfigurationProvider.java:**

```
@RewriteConfiguration
public class ExampleConfigurationProvider extends HttpConfigurationProvider
{
    @Override
    public int priority()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(final ServletContext context)
    {
        return ConfigurationBuilder.begin()
                .addRule()
                .when(Direction.isInbound().and(Path.matches("/test")))
                .perform(Forward.to("/index.xhtml"))

                .addRule()
                .when(Response.isCommitted())
                .perform(Lifecycle.abort());

    }
}
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I've already solved the problem by myself.
I definitely should've pay more attention to the Rewrite documentation.

The problem was with dependencies - I included all rewrite-* JARs from Maven to my application.
Now I left only rewrite-servlet.jar and everything works fine!